# Outlook forwarding email outside of the window defined

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I set up the following rules in Outlook 2010...

> Apply this rule after the message arrives
>   from someone@email.com
>   and with Report in the subject
>   and which has an attachment
>   and on this computer only
>   run `Project.ThisOutlookSession.MyScript`

The Script is as follows...

```
Sub methodName(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Item.Body = "Please find attached"
    Item.Save

   Dim bolTimeMatch As Boolean

    bolTimeMatch = (Time >= #7:00:00 AM#) Or (Time <= #7:30:00 AM#)
    If bolTimeMatch Then
        Set myForward = Item.Forward
        myForward.Recipients.Add "abc@hotmail.com"

        myForward.Send
    End If

    Set myForward = Nothing

End Sub
```

I would like this particular email to only send daily in the window defined (7:00am - 7:30am)... However it sent the email outside of the window. How could I change the code to only send at that time (UK hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the Outlook object model provides the [DeferredDeliveryTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869452.aspx) property which can be used to set a Date indicating the date and time the mail message is to be delivered.

Use the logical And operator instead:

```
 bolTimeMatch = (Time >= #7:00:00 AM#) And (Time <= #7:30:00 AM#)
```

Also you may try to use the *TimeValue(Now)* instead of *Time* statements.

Comment: thanks I used the `TimeValue(Now)` instead of `Time`. Did the trick